# Assign a liquid object to a variable in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify I am declaring a variable like this:

```
{% assign favourites = hello %}
```

Instead of the variable being `hello, I want to use a metafield from my product. I can get the metafield like this:

```
{{ product.metafields.global["other_options"] }}
```

I can't, however, merge the two together like this

```
 {% assign favourites = {{ product.metafields.global["other_options"] }} %}
```

I have tried wrapping the liquid object in single and double quotation marks but this doesn't work.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the internal braces :)

```
{% assign favourites = product.metafields.global["other_options"] %}
```